# Javascript not passing certain variables to child function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am not sure why this is happening but only certain variables are not passed into the child function scope, for example (in `nodejs`):

```
var json        = {some:'json'},
    pem         = require('pem'),
    ursa        = require('ursa'),
    sha256      = crypto.createHash('sha256'),
    _key        = 'a string',
    _iv         = 'a string',
    cipher      = crypto.createCipheriv( 'aes-256-cbc' , _key , _iv ),
    cert        = 'a string';

pem.getPublicKey(cert,function(err,publicKey){

        //AES Write
        cipher.write(new Buffer('string'),'utf8',function(err){ });

        //End AES Encryption
        cipher.end();

        //On AES Receive Data
        cipher.on('data', function(string){
            console.log( 'JSON: ', json ); //Works
            console.log( 'PEM: ', pem ); //Works
            console.log( 'Ursa: ', ursa ); //Works
            console.log( 'sha256: ', sha256 ); //Undefined
            console.log( '_key: ', _key ); //Works
            console.log( '_iv: ', _iv ); //Works
            console.log( 'cipher: ', cipher ); //Works
            console.log( 'cert: ', cert ); //Works
            console.log( 'publicKey: ', publicKey ); //Undefined
        });
});
```

Why would only some of the variables be passed, while others become undefined?

Comment: using crypto requires requiring crypto in first, doesn't it?

Comment: It's very hard to say without looking at all of the code, which isn't really feasible. My best guess is that `sha256` and `publicKey` are variables used within the pem library (which seems reasonable). Try changing the name of those variables and see if it works

Comment: Your use of the word "pass" is not really accurate here. There's no "passing" involved; those variables you reference are in scope inside that callback function, and the function will log whatever values they have when that callback runs.

Comment: @kinakuta - Yes Sorry, it was set in a different part of the code

Comment: @Rob M. it turns out that is correct! I tried the variable "key" before the use of "publicKey" which neither worked so I was a bit stumped, I tried a completely random variable and it picked it up - DOH! ;)

Comment: @Pointy - sorry, thought that was the easiest way to explain what I was trying to do :)

Comment: Whenever weird stuff like this pops up, my mind always goes to naming collision first. It's such a hard thing to debug that testing that theory can save a lot of time and headaches. Glad it worked! :)

Comment: @RobM. That seems highly dubious in a Node environment. Those are just local variable names.

Comment: @Pointy agreed, it was just a guess (seemed to fix the issue though)

Comment: Also @Pointy, here is a proof of concept on this: http://jsfiddle.net/np4kW/1/. It's not unreasonable to think that someone forgot a `var` keyword in their library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names of your variables might be reserved keywords by those libraries.